# ZwQueryDirectoryFile Buffer Overflow

Tags: windows, driver

I am trying to write Windows driver code to scan a directory for file names:

```
HANDLE directory_handle;
FILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION directory_information;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK io_status_block;
NTSTATUS status;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES directory_attributes;
InitializeObjectAttributes(&directory_attributes                   ,
                           &directory_name                         ,
                           OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,
                           0                                       ,
                           0                                       );
status = ZwCreateFile(&directory_handle                                 ,
                      FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY | SYNCHRONIZE                 ,
                      &directory_attributes                             ,
                      &io_status_block                                  ,
                      0                                                 ,
                      0                                                 ,
                      FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS                            ,
                      FILE_OPEN                                         ,
                      FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT | FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE,
                      0                                                 ,
                      0                                                 );
status = ZwQueryDirectoryFile(directory_handle             ,
                              NULL                         ,
                              0                            ,
                              0                            ,
                              &io_status_block             ,
                              &directory_information       ,
                              sizeof(directory_information),
                              FileBothDirectoryInformation ,
                              TRUE                         ,
                              NULL                         ,
                              FALSE                        );
status = ZwQueryDirectoryFile(directory_handle             ,
                              NULL                         ,
                              0                            ,
                              0                            ,
                              &io_status_block             ,
                              &directory_information       ,
                              sizeof(directory_information),
                              FileBothDirectoryInformation ,
                              TRUE                         ,
                              NULL                         ,
                              FALSE                        );
```

The first call to `ZwQueryDirectoryFile()` returns a `STATUS_SUCCESS` (`0x00000000`) result, but the second call returns a status of `STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW` (`0x80000005`).  Do you know what might cause this buffer-overflow error?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you consulted the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-zwquerydirectoryfile#remarks)? Starting with "On the first call to `ZwQueryDirectoryFile`..."

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the Windows-provided documentation online.  The documentation does not suggest why the second `ZwQueryDirectoryFile()` returns a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW indicates that the buffer isn't big enough to return the full filename (however we know the buffer is big enough for at least the base structure, else STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL).

What's happening here is the first call successfully returned the "." entry (as there is room in the base structure for a single character filename), but the second call failed with STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW because the buffer isn't big enough for the ".." entry.

Answer (score 0):

`FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION` is a variable-length structure.
You will need to allocate suffucient space to receive the path string at the end of the structure.

You will need to pass the size of the allocated buffer to `ZwQueryDirectoryFile` rather than `sizeof(FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)`

No idea why the first one works.